# Local DNS server for internal network & internet

Tags: networking, dns, routing

I'm using OSX and at work, I'm connected to internal network (en0) and to the internet (en2). I made a script to alter routing table so only traffic on certain subnets are routed to en0, rest is routed to en2. The problem is that I had to set the DNS server from the internal network as primary DNS server to be able to resolve internal hostnames.

My goal is to configure a local DNS server, which would primarily ask recursively to my ISP's DNS server and if it fails to resolve, then ask the DNS server from internal network.

Can you recommend a minimalistic software?
Thank you

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: using forwarders is often easier for people to configure and conceptualize, than recursion. Bind supports both forwarders and recursion.

Comment: Unbound and dnsmasq are the two most common options.

Comment: @FrankThomas: You are right. Because of lack the lack of knowledge I thought a recursive DNS server is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I installed dnsmasq and configed it with the following:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
cache-size=10000
no-poll
domain=<domain-of-local-network>
expand-hosts

server=/<domain-of-local-network>/<local-network-dns-server>
server=/<subnet1-from-local-network>.in-addr.arpa/<local-network-dns-server>
server=/<subnet2-from-local-network>.in-addr.arpa/<local-network-dns-server>
..
..
server=/<subnetN-from-local-network>.in-addr.arpa/<local-network-dns-server>

server=<dns-to-resolve-internet-dns-names>
```

I changed the title of this question because recursive DNS server was not necessary.